# How to connect hashtags to posts for a HashTag cloud in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

The HashTags that are made in new posts get connected to every other post in the database. I need them to connect only to posts that have the same hashtags to implement a hashtag cloud after. 
Something goes wrong, when i add a new post and make a new tag or even update an old tag, if i go to the admin section and check, the tag's are connected to all the posts in the database.

What am I doing wrong. Got stuck with this for a while.

Here is my code:

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from user_profile.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    # postad_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    # postad_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Global")
    # postad_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class HashTag(models.Model):
    """HashTag model"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My views.py

```
 class PostPost(View):
    """Post - post form available on page /user/<username> URL"""

    def post(self, request, username):

        form = PostForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # post = form.save(commit = False)
            # post.user = request.user
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            post = Post(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                user=user,
                # country=form.cleaned_data['country']
                )
            post.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#":
                    hashtag, created = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                    print(hashtag,'\n', created)
                    hashtag.post.add(post)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+username)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your code *does* connect hashtags and posts, and a hashtag is only connected to the post that uses that tag. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to implement a hashtag cloud, and something goes wrong, when i add a new post and make a new tag or even update an old tag, if i go to the admin section and check, the tag's are connected to all the posts in the database.

Comment: If something wrong with hashtag why you not change the name ?

Comment: That's not possible with the code you've posted. Are you sure it's not just the many-to-many widget showing you all the tags you can select?

Comment: Thank's I'll check that out. Maybe this is the issue. I will say for sure later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Thanks to everyone. But I tried many things and it did not help until i got a new version of django and did not use the same code again. I think the problem was in the version of django.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models
from user_profile.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    # postad_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    # postad_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Global")
    # postad_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        # This should be text, not name.
        return self.text

class HashTag(models.Model):
    """HashTag model"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



# Sometimes get or create dosnt work properly

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


class PostPost(View):
    """Post - post form available on page /user/<username> URL"""

    def post(self, request, username):

        form = PostForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # post = form.save(commit = False)
            # post.user = request.user
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            post = Post(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                user=user,
                # country=form.cleaned_data['country']
                )
            post.save()
            words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word[0] == "#":
                    try:
                        hashtag = HashTag.objects.get(name=word[1:])
                        created = False
                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        hashtag, created= HashTag.objects.create(name=word[1:])
                    print(hashtag,'\n', created)
                    hashtag.post.add(post)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+username)
```